# Do a calculation before returning attribute in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

Is it possible to change an attribute before it's value is returned in Laravel?

I have 2 ways of finding a sell price, the one implemented is just getting the price from the database, and the other is calculating it from a buy price with currency and advance.

Throughout the system i pull the price like this:

```
$product->baseprice;
```

Is it possible to run a model function like this:

```
public function baseprice(){
    if(is_null($this->baseprice){
       return $this->calculatePrice();
    }
    return $this->baseprice;
}
```

It's always one way or the other, baseprice will always be null if the sellprice should be calculated. 
when using $this->baseprice?
Comments are welcome if this is bad practice.

Comment: Keeping this in the model is not the best idea ever. If you have to use it in every controller and you're afraid of duplicating code, then good, you don't want to do that. Use a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and `use` that trait in whatever controller you need. It keeps things clean and still allows your function to be controller independent.

Comment: Haha wow three answers with the exact same answer in the same minute. Is that an SO record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an accessor. The [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) has plenty of good examples on how to use these, but in a nutshell you define a method in the form `get[Whatever]Attribute` and it allows you to call `$model->whatever` and get the output of that method.

So, your code will be something like this:

```
public function getBasepriceAttribute()
{
    if (is_null($this->attributes['baseprice'])) {
        return $this->calculatePrice();
    }

    return $this->attributes['baseprice'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change an attribute before it's value is returned from model by [Accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)